# Is it possible to run the Zwift trainer software on a Linux distribution?

Tags: wine

I might want to run Zwift on a Linux distribution instead of Windows.

Is this at all possible? Anyone got experience running it with WineHQ?

**Edit:** the reason I'd want to run it on a PC is that I use the companion app on my phone and don't have a tablet. The PC is also preferable because the screen size is larger than on a tablet if I would have one.

Currently I am using Windows, so right now there is no problem. Although, since Microsoft has some marketing strategies in place where people are drawn to Windows 10, where they might start ripping people of by asking them for a monthly/yearly charge to use Windows 10 and upward in the future. I'm considering changing from Windows to Linux, because I don't want to buy into their strategy. Unfortunately there is too much software that is not available on Linux. It'd just be nice if other companies embraced developing applications for all operating systems. That's why I'm asking around if anyone knows a good way to handle this with Zwift.

Comment: It wouldn't be financially viable for zwift to even start considering a Linux OS as their users probably account for 1% with a Linux system. They did talk briefly around 2018 about different OS platforms but that's as far as it got. You mention wine but that's a Mac OS platform so why not just use the IOS version?

Comment: @DanK Wine is originally for Linux. Perhaps it does also exist for mac and other BSD Unixes, but originally it is for Linux. The question is completely legitimate. That someone was not successful 2 years ago is a hint, but maybe the person just missed some step.

Comment: @vladimir it wouldn't be impossible to get zwift running on Linux I guess it boils down to how much time the OP has to reverse engineer what's available. It's doable but probably easier to side load it through windows using wine or a parallel equivalent

Comment: With the ditch proprietary and go open source thing, I feel your pain.  For now, I feel that Windows in a VM is where it belongs, allowing me to do the stuff I need to that's not available natively on Linux.  It's kind of like choosing to use a bike instead of a car to commute I suppose.  Sometimes you have no choice but to use a car, even though you'd really rather not...  Interesting how lines between tech and other stuff are so easy to blur BTW.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zwift can now be run in Linux using the latest versions of Wine (5.0 and greater) and the workaround from user wentam42 detailed in comment #7 of [this bug report](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46313).

Here are the steps. You can also find a video documenting the process [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFrsCqLg-30).

1. Install [`Wine 5.0+`](https://www.winehq.org/) following the instructions for your distribution
2. Install [`winetricks`](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) script
3. Run `winetricks dotnet35sp1 win7`
4. Download the `RunFromProcess.exe` utility from nirsoft [here](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_from_process.html)
5. Download the [Windows installation file](https://cdn.zwift.com/app/ZwiftSetup.exe) for Zwift
6. Run `wine ZwiftSetup.exe` and wait for the installation to complete (~1hr for me)
7. At this point you will be greeted by a blank white window. *Leaving this window open* (or relaunching `wine ZwiftLauncher.exe` if you closed the window), run `wine RunFromProcess.exe ZwiftLauncher.exe ZwiftApp.exe`
8. The Zwift splash screen should open followed by a login prompt. Proceed until you are prompted to connect sensors.
9. **Bluetooth compatibility in Wine is currently immature**. However, I had no trouble using the Zwift Companion app on my phone to sync with sensors. The phone app then relays the information to the Zwift servers so that you can ride.
10. After launching Zwift Companion, turn on relevant settings (e.g., for BLE sensors, location and bluetooth), pedal, and in Zwift click 'Search sensors'. Everything from this point forward should work as it does natively in Windows.

Comment: When I run RunFromProcess.exe I get an "Error 2: File not found." in a windows dialog box. This makes sense because there is no ZwiftApp.exe. Presumably this is because ZwiftApp.exe is no longer part of the installed files from Zwift (there is still ZwiftLauncher.exe). Also, the installation didn't go quite as expected from these instructions. I have a feeling that the installer has changed somewhat since this was written. The installer no longer starts Zwift itself, yet when started manually you still get the white screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Intel video card, maybe you need to do an workaround due to @wentam42 together with the @BikeMan procedure, which is to overide the MESA GL version. Run the following before starting Zwift:

- export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.1

If it does not work, you can try also:

- export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.4COMPACT

There is an bugzilla (the source of this workaround) issue for Intel users here:
https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48613

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of installing and managing Zwift on linux yourself, you can get it prepackaged and preinstalled in a sandboxed environment that has all the necessary dependencies.

Simply run it and get pedaling!

https://github.com/netbrain/zwift

Gone are the days of having to manage your own problematic zwift installation, failing updates and changing dependencies.

Full disclosure, I'm the author of this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the Wine site, [Zwift is rated as garbage](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17923).  However, the latest version of Wine is 5.0 so it might be worth having a go...

Perhaps your other option is to run Windows in a virtual machine.  My laptop runs Fedora and I have recently installed Windows 10 Pro as a Gnome Boxes guest.  It runs very well for what I needed it for which included using Garmin Express.  It all depends on how well the Spice Windows guest tools works with Zwift in terms of graphics I guess...

Comment: If the aim is to use the app legally without Windows license, virtual machine doesn't really help.

Comment: My Windows 10 guest OS is completely legal.  Once I was happy I'd got it set up right, I bought a product key and activated it.

Comment: Of course. If you read the question, there's the rant about Microsoft and the mention of "want to run Zwift on a Linux distribution instead of Windows" that sounds like the OP wants to run Zwift without involving Windows at all. Windows in a virtual machine under Linux host is still Windows.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't see that edit...